# DataGridView designer picked false table

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, ef-code-first

I have the standard datagridview in my WinForms application. I already have added some tables to the DataGridView regarding to the Code First Classes that have been created by Visual Studio. All tables have been added as they should but now I want to add another table with relationships to the DataGridView but in this case it won't work. The designer picked the false table.

My tables:

**Transactions:**

```
Id : int (Primary Key)

date : date

bookieId : int (Foreign Key)

kindOfTransactionId: int (Foreign Key)

amout : money

comment : varchar(80)
```

**Bookie:**

```
Id : int (Primary Key)

bookie : varchar
```

**kindOfTransaction:**

```
Id : int (Primary Key)

kindOfTransaction : varchar
```

Now I did the following:

- Open DataGridView designer (clicked the arrow in the top right corner)
- Clicked on the Dropdown for 'Choose Data Source' and picked 'add Project Data Source'
- Now I choosed the Object Data Source Type -> Next
- Picked the 3 classes (Transactions, Bookie, kindOfTransactions)
- Finished this mask

After all these steps I expected, that the columns from the Transactions Class would be displayed but instead of this I get the Columns (Id, kindOfTransaction, Transactions) from the kindOfTransactions class displayed.

Relationships are set like this:
Bookie.Id (PK) -> Transactions.bookieId (FK)
kindOfTransaction.Id (PK) -> Transactions.kindOfTransactionId (FK)

What is my fault in this case?